# Getting Mysql results where subquery is not null

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am working on a query that will get the count of items using a sub query, where the result of both sub queries is not null.

I have this query

```
SELECT s.id, (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM salesItems WHERE sale_id = s.id AND status = 'S') AS shipped, (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM salesItems WHERE sale_id = s.id AND (status = 'A' OR status = 'B')) AS unshipped FROM `sales` s WHERE s.status = 'A' OR s.status = 'B'
```

Which produces this:

```
id   | shipped | unshipped
1500 |   NULL  |    2
1501 |   NULL  |    1
1502 |   NULL  |    1
1503 |    1    |    2
1504 |    2    |  NULL
1505 |    2    |    5
```

I only want results where shipped and unshipped have a positive value. I have tried several things, such as

```
SELECT s.id, (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM salesItems WHERE sale_id = s.id AND status = 'S' HAVING SUM(qty) > 0) AS shipped, (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM salesItems WHERE sale_id = s.id AND (status = 'A' OR status = 'B') HAVING SUM(qty) > 0) AS unshipped FROM `sales` s WHERE s.status = 'A' OR s.status = 'B'
```

And

```
SELECT s.id, (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM salesItems WHERE sale_id = s.id AND status = 'S') AS shipped, (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM salesItems WHERE sale_id = s.id AND (status = 'A' OR status = 'B')) AS unshipped FROM `sales` s WHERE s.status = 'A' OR s.status = 'B' AND (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM salesItems WHERE sale_id = s.id AND status = 'S') IS NOT NULL AND (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM salesItems WHERE sale_id = s.id AND (status = 'A' OR status = 'B')) IS NOT NULL
```

Both still return the same results.

I created a DB Fiddle, but it shows no results found, which I ran the same code through MySql and it returns all items

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mHuQ4nCHZVPmEacog1iQvq/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Arganas answer, you can use `HAVING`

```
SELECT s.id, 
(
SELECT SUM(qty) 
FROM salesItems 
WHERE sale_id = s.id AND status = 'S'
) AS shipped, 
(
SELECT SUM(qty) 
FROM salesItems 
WHERE sale_id = s.id AND (status = 'A' OR status = 'B')
) AS unshipped 
FROM `sales` s 
WHERE (s.status = 'A' OR s.status = 'B') 
HAVING shipped is not Null and unshipped is not null
```

this is the fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mHuQ4nCHZVPmEacog1iQvq/1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(qty),0) ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no SQL expert by any strech, but it seems as if this should work.

```
SELECT s.id, 
(
SELECT SUM(qty) 
FROM salesItems 
WHERE sale_id = s.id AND status = 'S'
) AS shipped, 
(
SELECT SUM(qty) 
FROM salesItems 
WHERE sale_id = s.id AND (status = 'A' OR status = 'B')
) AS unshipped 
FROM `sales` s 
WHERE (s.status = 'A' OR s.status = 'B') and 
shipped is not Null and 
unshipped is not null
```

Comment: I tried that, it returns "#1054 - Unknown column 'shipped' in 'where clause'"